# htaccess restrict file download by size

Tags: .htaccess

I know you can use htaccess directives to prevent certain file types from being downloaded.  But I am curious if anyone knows if you can prevent files from being downloaded based on a size limit?  So for instance if a filesize is greater than 1MB then it is off limits.